# How to serve Angular application in dev mode?

Tags: angular, typescript

According to multiple sources (like e.g. [this one](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3387)), I'm supposed to be able to switch between different environments by specifying the name in the following way.

```
ng serve --environment=dev
```

If I understand the setup correctly, my *.angular-cli.json* file points to the *environments/environment.ts* for the flag value *dev* and to the *environments/environment.prod.ts* for the *prod* value.

```
"environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
"environments": {
  "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
  "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
}
```

The issue is that when I execute the one quoted in the first example, I still get to see the prod version. (I print out the whole *environment* object in the constructor of the accessed component.) I even tried to add the *target* flag, although I'm rather certain that's only the optimization level while running build. No difference...

```
ng serve --environment=dev --target=development
```

What am I missing and how can I make the *serve* command run with *environments/environment.ts*?

**edit**

The contents of *main.ts* are as follows.

```
import { enableProdMode } from "@angular/core";
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";

import { AppModule } from "./app/app.module";
import { environment } from "./environments/environment";

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `production: false` inside `environment.ts`?

Comment: @JoãoGhignatti Yes, that's what I have in that file (see the answer by Joshua below). Any idea on that?

Comment: What does main.ts and angular-cli.json look like? I really want to help you get to the bottom of this. It sounds like something is not right because all your code so far should serve up a dev environment.

Answer (score 5):

As of 2020, use `configurations` instead of environments.

```
"start:dev": "ng serve -c dev"
```

Instead of

```
"start:dev": "ng serve --env=dev"
```

This works for `serve` and `build`. `angular.json` should look something like this:

```
"configurations": {
  "dev": {
    "optimization": true,
    "outputHashing": "all",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "extractCss": true,
    "namedChunks": false,
    "aot": true,
    "extractLicenses": true,
    "vendorChunk": false,
    "buildOptimizer": true,
    "fileReplacements": [
      {
        "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
        "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: -c dev is similar to  --configuration=dev ?

Comment: exactly! just a shortcut

Answer (score 1):

I have in my `angular-cli.json` this configuration:

```
  "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
  "environments": {
    "dev": "environments/ava-mec/environment.dev.ts",
    "prod": "environments/ava-mec/environment.prod.ts",
    "hmg": "environments/ava-mec/environment.hmg.ts"
  },
```

And in my `package.json` this `scripts` set:

```
"start-ava-mec-prod": "ng serve --app=ava-mec --environment=prod",
"start-ava-mec-hmg": "ng serve --app=ava-mec --environment=hmg",
"start-ava-mec-dev": "ng serve --app=ava-mec --environment=dev",
"build-ava-mec-local": "ng build --prod --app=ava-mec --environment=hmg --base-href './' --verbose && rsync dist/ /Library/WebServer/Documents/avamec/ --recursive --delete --exclude=.git*  --verbose",
```

As i can see, the difference is that i'm using the application configuration (and using --app to define witch application i'm using). And on the `build` command i'm using --prod to enable the AOT compiler. For me this works fine. The variables set on my environments file become acessible on my code fine.

Comment: Just FYI - I believe that AOT is set to true by default now. Accept for that, I tried to set the extra depth in the directory and go with *--app* flag. No change. Would you be able to move one of the files to the environment directly and see if the command still behaves as expected (while skipping the *--app* flag)? I want to confirm that it's my system that's misbehaving.

Answer (score -1):

```
 ng serve -env=dev
```

This will use the `"dev"` key's value in `environments/environment.ts`

If that is not working for you, then make sure that environment.ts has `production: false` in the `environment.ts` like so...

```
export const environment = {
    production: false
};
```

Also it could be that you are enabling prod mode somewhere in main.ts

If all else fails you could start a new cli project that would have correct settings and save some trouble.

Comment: I'm running precisely what you have there - both the command and the exported values. It doesn't access that file. Instead it goes for *environment.prod.ts*. What can be wrong? I'm out of ideas.

Comment: What does your main.ts look like?

Comment: I do highly appreciate your attempts to support me. Because I wanted to show respect for it and for your time, I tried to dig some more on my own. This far, I came up with nada, zero and ziltch. It appears that it works for some people and works not for others. I suspect it might have to do with system specific platform used to create the application (even if using the same tool set, i.e. angular-cli package). Please see the edit in my question for the contents of *main.ts*.

Comment: Did you have time to peek at the addition to the question showing the contents of *main.ts*?

Comment: `-env=dev` option doesn't exist